# Xamarin - Could not determine Android SDK location

Tags: android, .net, xamarin

Getting an error when I try to build blank app. 
I have tried uninstalling and installing Android SDK from the SDK Manager in Visual Studio 2017 but the problem persists.

I have checked in Tools > Options > Xamarin and the Android SDK Location points to the correct folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Any ideas?

[image: Error Messsgae]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

After alot of trial and error I ended up installing as many components as I could, I don't know which one worked but this is the list of all installed, and it ended up working.